# Persistent cookies in node js express

Tags: node.js, cookies, express

I am trying to implement remember me user in my express js code. In this if user check the remember me user then we need to remember the user credential for 14 days.

I have set credential details in cookie and tried to fetch the credential from cookie for the next visit.

```
//set cookie value
res.cookie('email', emailId);

//retrieve cookie value
req.cookies.email;
```

If I close the browser and open it again then these cookie values are not persisting and I am getting credential as undefined.

We have used below modules:

```
var express      = require('express')
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')
var app = express()
app.use(cookieParser())
```

Please let me know how to persist cookie value on restarting browser.

Thanks,
-- Sandy

Comment: [express-sessions](https://github.com/konteck/express-sessions) does what you want automatically!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two things to look into:

First, are you setting the cookie expiration? Try setting to:

```
res.cookie('email', emailId, { maxAge: 900000, httpOnly: true });
```

Secondly, make sure that you aren't clearing cookies, etc. when the browser is closed (I clear mine).

Comment: How do I set the session expiry to infinite? 1/0 ? I don't want the cookie to expire ever unless the user manually removes them from browser.