# Retain cookie even after browser is closed

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cookies, jwt

I am setting a cookie in Node-Express JS with JWT token as part of cookie with following code.

```
var token = jwt.sign(parsed.data, "token_secret", {expiresIn: "43200m"});

res.setHeader('Set-Cookie', 'token='+token+';expires='+new Date(new Date().getTime()+9940900000).toUTCString());
```

On closing or quitting the browser the cookie is getting deleted. 
What is the best way to retain the cookie? Is it storing the token in localStorage in browser and attaching it to header for every http request? Or is there any other way of setting cookie, so that cookie is not deleted after browser is closed.

Comment: cookies have =nothing to do with browser close, it just depends on expiry time. so you must not be setting it correct.

Comment: expire time of cookie is 2016-11-13T05:51:27.016Z(copied from browser) and token is around a month.

Comment: **I cannot reproduce the problem** . Since you didn't provide a proper [MCVE] I had to take a couple of liberties, but when I ran [my test case](http://hastebin.com/lelubecixa.js) in Firefox, quit Firefox entirely, and then loaded it up again: The cookie was sent from Firefox to the server. Whatever the problem is, it doesn't seem to be caused by the code in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this

```
    document.cookie = cName + "=" + cValue + "; expires=" + expDate + ";path=/";
```

Answer (score -2):

There are different types of cookies available, to know Refer [HTTP Cookie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie)

One of which are **session cookie**, here is definition from wiki,

> A session cookie, also known as an in-memory cookie or transient cookie, exists only in temporary memory while the user navigates the website.[13] Web browsers normally delete session cookies when the user closes the browser.[14] Unlike other cookies, session cookies do not have an expiration date assigned to them, which is how the browser knows to treat them as session cookies.

So if you don't want your cookie to expire after browser close then use **Persistent Cookie**.

To do so refer,
[Persistent cookies in node js express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26440117/persistent-cookies-in-node-js-express)

Hope that helps!

Comment: You've quoted a lot of material about session cookies, which the OP doesn't want to use, and which don't have an expert date … when the code in the question shows an attempt to set an expiry date. Then, when you finally get around to explaining what to do… you give up and just make it a link to another question (which should have been a close as duplicate vote)

Comment: Am sorry if you don't understand the purpose of answer, the answer clearly explains the purpose of cookie usage (in general) which is the cause of the problem user posted, so I don't have to be an NodeJS developer (which am not) to explain how to use cookies to solve the user solution

Comment: A general explanation as to how cookies work does not explain "the cause of the problem user posted". If the code in the question didn't set an expiry date, then such an explanation might answer it (although it wouldn't be a very good answer since it doesn't clearly state the specific problem), however, since the code in the question *does* set an expiry date, I don't see that it answers it at all.